# Como atribuir imagem a um Item do ListView?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-berlin

Como atribuir uma Imagem a um Item do ListView? Estou querendo colocar uma imagem de acordo com o status do processo. Inicialmente só conseguir fazendo statusbar com componentes externos, porém não posso usar externos. Então usarei uma Imagem de acordo o status mudará a cor, pois retângulo não consegui também. É o seguinte que estou tentando:

```
var
  listStatusExame           : TList<TImage>;
  txtStatusExame            : TListItemImage;
begin
  listStatusExame           := TList<TImage>.Create;

  listview1.BeginUpdate;

  for I := 0 to (listview1.Items.Count - 1) do
  begin
    txtStatusExame := TListItemImage(lvwAtendimentos.Items[i].Objects.FindDrawable
      ('status_img'));
    listStatusExame.add(Image1);
    txtStatusExame.ImageSource.ImageList := ImageList1;
  end;
end.
```

Se alguém souber como adicionar um retângulo em um Item do ListView, seria melhor ainda, por gentileza.

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi bem sua dúvida, a forma mais simples seria vincular um ImageList ao ListView e então indicar no item do ListView o índice da imagem que será usada.

É possível alterar a imagem em tempo de execução.

Como eu estou um pouco sem tempo para criar uma aplicação de exemplo eu acabei tirando uns prints de fazendo uma edição no Paint mesmo para mostrar o que eu estou falando.

Espero que te ajude.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se não ficou muito claro me avisa, posso tentar melhorar a explicação.